# Java: I want to adjust the size of a thread pool. How can I detect either CMS collection starts, or other system-wide factors affecting available CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

(The specifics for this question are for a mod for Minecraft. In general, the question deals with resizing a threadpool based on system load and CPU availability).

I am coming from an Objective C background, and Apple's libdispatch (Grand Central Dispatch) for thread scheduling.

The immediate concern I have is trying to reduce the size of the threadpool when a CMS tenured collection is running. The program in question (Minecraft) only works well with CMS collections. A much less immediate, but still "of interest", is reducing the threadpool size when other programs are demanding significant CPU (specifically, either a screen recorder, or a twitch stream).

In Java, I have just found out about (deep breath):
Executors, which provide access to thread pools (both fixed size, and adjustable size), with cached thread existence (to avoid the overhead of constantly re-creating new threads, or to avoid the worry of coding threads to pause and resume based on workload),
Executor (no s), which is the generic interface for saying "Now it is time to execute this runnable()",
ExecutorService, which manages the threadpools according to Executor,
ThreadPoolExecutor, which is what actually manages the thread pool, and has the ability to say "This is the maximum number of threads to use".

Under normal operation, about 5 times a second, there will be 50 high priority, and 400 low priority operations submitted to the thread pool per user on the server. This is for high-powered machines.

What I want to do is:

1. Work with less-powerful machines. So, if a computer only has 2 cores, and the main program (two primary threads, plus some minor assistant threads) is already maxing out the CPU, these background tasks will be competing with the main program and the garbage collector. In this case, I don't want to reduce the number of background threads (it will probably stay at 2), but I do want to reduce how much work I schedule. So this is just "How do I detect when the work-load is going up". I suspect that this is just a case of watching the size of the work queue I use when Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

But the first problem: I can't find anything to return the size of the work queue! ThreadPoolExecutor() can return the queue, and I can ask that for a size, but newCachedThreadPool() only returns an ExecutorService, which doesn't let me query for size (or rather, I don't see how to).

2. If I have "enough cores", I want to tell the pool to use more threads. Ideally, enough to keep CPU usage near max. Most of the tasks that I want to run are CPU bound (disk I/O will be the exception, not the rule; concurrency blocking will also be rare). But I don't want to heavily over-schedule threads. How do I determine "enough threads" without going way over the available cores?
3. If, for example, screen recording (or streaming) activates, CPU core usage by other programs will go up, and then I want to reduce the number of threads; as the number of threads go down, and queue backlog goes up, I can reduce the amount of tasks I add to the queue. But I have no idea how to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best advice I / we can give is to not try to "micro-manage" the number of threads in the thread pools.  Set it to sensible size that is proportional to the number of physical cores ... and leave it.  By all means provide some static tuning parameters (e.g. in config files), but don't to make the system tune itself dynamically.  (IMO, the chances that dynamic tuning will work better than static are ... pretty slim.)

For "real-time" streaming, your success is going to depend on the overall load and the scheduler's ability to prioritize more than the number of threads.  However it is a fact that standard Java SE on a standard OS is not suited to hard real-time, so your real-time performance is liable to deteriorate badly if you push the envelope.

Comment: That's ... not quite the answer I wanted :).

I certainly want to use as much spare CPU as possible; what I want to run will generally be CPU bound, except that I've realized that I have a horrible "Dining philosophers" issue that will cause me locking concerns. And the simple approach to that will leave idle CPU.

Comment: Sorry, let me try that again.  
  
It's not "Real time". It's more like "Available time". There will be some work that is "must do", even if it slows the game down. There will be some work that is "As available CPU permits", that should be treated as a very low priority job -- don't disturb anything else running, but do this if there is spare CPU available.  
  
Fixed number of threads: The problem is that it can change. If nothing else is running on the system, then there's a reasonable number of threads to use, that will depend on the computer. But things change. Moving around in-game, etc.

Comment: The best way to deal with your (restated) problem is to use thread priorities.  Adjusting thread pool sizes is too complicated. I have serious doubts that you can get dynamic pool sizes to work at all ... let alone get it to be sufficiently responsize for your needs.

Comment: As for your "dining philosophers" problem, there are known strategies for avoiding or detecting / breaking deadlocks.  You should not have to wear idle CPUs to solve it,

Comment: The strategies I have seen for dealing with Dining Philosopher's deadlock either require some communication/"waiter", or else some sort of "I release locks, go to sleep for some time, and try again". Going to sleep implies wasted CPU/idle cores. Worse, (key point of this locking problem), since the main game server thread has no synchronization concepts, even if I can make it wait for these background calculations, it could wind up sleeping longer than player response is acceptable.

Comment: (grr, cannot add paragraphs). As for thread priorities: I did not know about them before. After reading up on them, I'm left with "Needing to use them implies a bigger problem", as there is no guarantee at all about what they do. Specifically, they will behave differently on linux/Mac OS/Microsoft Windows. So, not a good idea.

Comment: Feel free to ignore my advice :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be ignoring you.  
  
Even without micro-managing the threadpool size, and being willing to let some idle CPU go unused: thread priorities, because they have differing functions on different OS's, and on some OS's act as starvation, and on others act as "reduced but still guaranteed to run", they just do not do the job. They cannot be a solution, because they don't have any dependable behavior.

(320K reputation is not just given out; you have helped others, and know what you're talking about. I think this is just a rare oversight.)

@Stephen c